# Missing a Visual Studio 2010 file in Windows 8.1

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-8.1

I upgraded to Windows 8.1 this morning. When I started Visual Studio 2010, I got the following error message right after the splash appeared:

> The file `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Microsoft.Vsa.tlb` could not be loaded. An attempt to repair this condition failed because the file could not be found.
>   Please reinstall this program.

Once I dismiss the error, Visual Studio loads up. Everything seems to be running ok, but everything I'm working on is using Framework versions 3.5 and greater. Should I be worried?

Comment: Do you have the .net 2.0 library selected in your project?  Does the error appear if you start a new project?

Comment: There was something about the migation that Visual Studio didn't like so I would reinstall `.NET Framework 2.0`

Comment: I didn't even have .net 2.0 installed on this machine. It was a relatively clean VM running almost nothing except VS 2010. Only .net 4 was installed. Fixed by installing .net 2.0 as @ramhound suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "Turn Windows features on or off" to install .NET 3.5 (includes 2.0 and 3.0).